# Why is the matrix function showing the number of columns 100

Tags: r, regression

In this example code I define the `X1=matrix(rnorm(length(y)*100), nrow = length(y));` I get the number of **rows 97** which is correct, but the number of **columns 100**.

When I multiply with 10 instead with 100 in: `X1=matrix(rnorm(length(y)*10` the number of columns is then 10.

I don't know why that is? Since I didn't assign any value for the columns.

```
library(glmnet)
library(ncvreg)
data("prostate");
X=prostate[,1:8];
y=prostate$lpsa; #97 values
X1=matrix(rnorm(length(y)*100), nrow = length(y)); #97x100
nrow(X1); ncol(X1);
```

Comment: The `matrix` function infers (if possible) the number of rows or columns. In your example, the data you put in the matrix has a length of 9700; since you specified that the number of rows must be 97, you need 100 columns to contain all the data.

Comment: @nicola thank you a lot, yes that is true. I didn't think of that.